# VS2013 and WPTooklit (version from AUG 2013)

Tags: windows-phone-8, visual-studio-2013, wptoolkit

Quick question for anyone out there.  I'm trying to install the August edition of the NuGet package of the wptoolkit.  Unfortunately, I can't get it to show up under VS2013 Pro.  Has anyone been able to get this to work?

Comment: Where do you expect it to show up?  It should just show up in the references of your app.  Worked fine for me.

Comment: Scott, Thanks for the reply... 
I have tried running it from package manager command line, and the ui version.  I have the 'Toolkit.Content' Resource.  When I look in my references, I get Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit showing up there.  I know it's installed.. but I expect to see the 'listpicker' control, and the other controls to show up in a toolbox somewhere.  This is what i'm missing..

Comment: Pretty sure that you have to add them yourself to the Toolbox.

Comment: I tried doing that.. They're not in the list for any of the components, and if I try to browse to the .dll to add them, it says there are no components.  I even tried to compile them myself and add the reference.  No dice.  How did you get it to work?

Answer (score 2):

You would have to browse to the dll which contains the controls to add them to the toolbox. In my project browse to the Packages folder of that project and then go to WPtoolkit.4.2013.08.16\lib\sl4-windowsphone71\Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit.dll

Even though it is a WP8 project, it only seems to work if you put in the 7.1 dll in the toolbox, otherwise if does not load.  The only controls that don't work are LongListSelector and MultiSelect as they are now part of the base WP8 framework controls.  Even though they are in the toolbox, when you try to drop them on your page you will get an error.  All other controls seem to work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

It should show up once you obtained it from NuGet.

1. Open `Package Manager`
2. Type in `Install-Package WPtoolkit` and press enter

Then, it'll be downloaded and imported into your project, so it should show up in the References folder.